# error while spliting a text value inside a dataframe column into induvial column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like below which I want split and create two seperate columns

**Mycode**

```
df['data'] =['cricket:sachin,football:messi,cricket:lara,tennis:nadal,tennis:serina']
df[["L1", "L2"]] = df["data"].str.split(pat=",", expand=True)
```

**Error**

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

```
**Expected Output**

L1        L2
cricket   sachin
football  messi
cricket   lara
tennis    nadal
tennis    serina
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['data'].str.split(',', expand=True).melt()['value']\
          .str.split(':', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'L1', 1:'L2'})
```

Output:

```
         L1      L2
0   cricket  sachin
1  football   messi
2   cricket    lara
3    tennis   nadal
4    tennis  serina
```

Details:

Split the string on ',' first, with expand=True to get a dataframe, then melt the columns to rows and split the value column on ':' then rename column headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
(df["data"].str.split(',')
           .explode()
           .str.split(':', expand=True)
           .rename(columns={0: 'L1', 1: 'L2'})
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
         L1      L2
0   cricket  sachin
1  football   messi
2   cricket    lara
3    tennis   nadal
4    tennis  serina
```